# Как сделать переход между листами Ecxel в DGV на C#?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

сможете ли подсказать как сделать переход между листами Ecxel файла который открыт в datagridview,что можно было выбирать листы?

Comment: Биндить листы отдельно. А выбор листа засунуть или в кнопки или в листбокс... или в Таб-контрол или в радио или ещё куда-то где можно выбирать.

Comment: А в каком смысле биндить, я при загрузке обращаюсь к номеру листа, как за биндить тогда? Если может быть разное количество листов?

Comment: "я при загрузке обращаюсь к номеру листа" - 1. вы можете загружать в грид разные листы. биндить  - это загружать с помощью ф-ции bind.  2. Вы можете поставить несколько гридов, и отображать один. Не помню есть ли в с# страничность, по идее должна быть, можно создать много страниц  и на каждой по гриду с загружеными разными страницами.